# How to get notification when I changed the Region Format in Settings

Tags: ios, notifications

What I want to do is to change the time format when I changed the Region Format from English to China in iPad `Settings->General->International->Region Format`.

I have tried this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateCalendar) name: UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification object:nil];

-(void)updateCalendar{
    self.text=[Toolbox formatDate:dateFormatter WithFormateString:@"EEEE MMMM dd"];
}
```

But it didn't work. I cann't get any notification. Perhaps `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` doesn't work for notification of Region Format changing. Is there A Notification type can do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Register for the `NSCurrentLocaleDidChangeNotification` notification. This will be called when the user returns to your app after the Region Format has changed.

The `UIApplicationSignificantTimeChangeNotification` notification is for time changes, not locale changes.